# Упоминание зарегистрированных названий

Tags: авторские-права, юридические-аспекты

Могу ли я без явного разрешения правообладателя использовать зарегистрированное им название (Facebook, Ferari, Formula 1 и т.д.) в своем ПО, предназначенном для получении прибыли мне. Или как получить это разрешение? И как трудно?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: можно... =)

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Но если это ПО, которое будет приносить большую прибыль или станет очень популярным - на него начнут обращать внимание, вот тогда и будут проблемы.

На счет торговых марок: в своей стране ты можешь зарегистрировать марку facebook если она еще не зарегистрирована, и использовать это имя. Но фейсбук может отсудить при желании.

Comment: А как обезопасить себя от такого? писать в представительство компании и заключать с каждой из них договоры на использования названий?

Comment: Известную торговую марку зарегистрировать не сможешь.

Comment: На странице о программе напиши кому принадлежат эти торговые марки - видел так часто делают.